# Why is JQuery Prev() object not giving me an Id?

Tags: jquery

I have an image that when clicked needs to grab the ID of the div previous to the image's parent div. The prev() method returns an object but the ID is always undefined. Here's what I have:

```
function getParentDiv(thisitem,action) {
    while (thisitem && (thisitem.tagName != "DIV" || !thisitem.id))
        thisitem = thisitem.parentNode;
    if (thisitem) checkForSibling(thisitem);
}

function checkForSibling(thisitem) {
    var thisDivId = thisitem.id;
    var sibling = $("#"+thisDivId).prev("div").attr("id");
}
```

Why is sibling always undefined?

EDIT:

I'm working within the constraints of a system we have at work, and so have to host the javascript from a location outside the application and call functions form there (not sure if that makes a difference). Here's how I create a new div that contains the images that call the above functions:

```
function createNewTextElementDiv(divName, placeHolder, elType, elSize, elSpacing) {
document.getElementById(placeHolder).innerHTML += "<div id='"+divName+"'><table width='465'><tr><td width='170px' valign='top'><span class='smallgreybold'>Text Element</span>&nbsp;<span class='mediumorangebold' style='font-size: 20;'>+</span></td><td width='295px' align='right' valign='center'><img src='/html/106789/arrow-up.png' style='border:0; height:20px; width:20px; background-color:transparent' onclick='getParentDiv(this,\"Up\")'></img>&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src='/html/106789/arrow-down.png' style='border:0; height:20px; width:20px; background-color:transparent' onclick='getParentDiv(this,\"Down\");'></img>&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src='/html/106789/remove-button.png' style='border:0; height:20px; width:20px; background-color:transparent' onclick='getParentDiv(this,\"Remove\");'></img></td></tr></table><span class='smallgrey'>Text Type: </span><span class='smallgreybold'>"+elType+"</span><span class='smallgrey'>&nbsp;&nbsp;Text Size: </span><span class='smallgreybold'>"+elSize+"</span><span class='smallgrey'>&nbsp;&nbsp;Spacing: </span><span class='smallgreybold'>"+elSpacing+"</span><br><hr></div>"; }
```

There are some static divs in the application as well as those I'm creating on the fly, hence I need the Id of the div previous to the parent. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Post your HTML code and the way you call your JS code, please.

Comment: You are mixing jQuery and pure JS so it is a bit hard to figure out what is wrong here. I suggest a jQuery solution: `$(thisitem).closest("div").prev("div").attr("id")`. Hope that helps

Comment: I was trying to avoid using jQuery tbh, but hit a brick wall, so threw the towel in and turned to jQuery!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use it like this:

```
function checkForSibling(thisitem) {
    var thisDivId = thisitem.id;
    var sibling = $("#"+thisDivId).parent().prev("div").attr("id");
}
```

needs to add .parent()

Comment: Please alert(thisDivId); and check if it is giving you correct ID.

Comment: That's giving me the expected Id

Comment: Can you please share HTML?

Comment: The system I'm working on gives access to an XML abstract of the application only, so I cannot directly edit the underlying HTML. Also it contains a lot of refs to other resources (javascript/vb libraries etc.) that are built into the system. I've supplied part of the page source but I'm not sure it'll be that useful to you tbh. https://jsfiddle.net/rg1c8vew/

Comment: I change prev() to prevAll() and along with your suggested addition of .parent() it works! Thanks for your help.